# How to add Navigation to a List of elements in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, navigation

I have model Class called **`Categories`**

```
class Categories {  //Categories class
  final String route;
  final String categoryName;
  final String categorySubTitle;
  Categories({this.route, this.categoryName, this.categorySubTitle});
}
```

And I created a list in which I put all the objects of the class I created .

```
List<Categories> categories = [tarocchi, sogni]; //List of categories

final Categories tarocchi = Categories(
  route: '/tarocchi',
  categoryName: 'Tarocchi e Divinazione',
  categorySubTitle: 'L’antica arte dei Tarocchi e della Divinazione',
);
final Categories sogni = Categories(
  route: '/sogni',
  categoryName: 'Interpretazione dei Sogni',
  categorySubTitle: 'Significato e interpretazione dei Sogni',
);
```

Each item in the list must go to a different screen.
In the list I generated, there will be an onTap function that will push to a different screen:

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: categories.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => Text(categories[index].categorySubTitle)
                      // here I call the new screens according with screens in the List
                      ),
                ),
                child: Card(
                  child: Text(categories[index].categoryName),
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
```

Comment: I'd like to ask you to share the screen design to get the whole picture of the problem, But I prefer to use Widget instead of  Route, so you can preset Widgets as a fragment.

Comment: nono you didnt get who talk about lenght?
I need to use the class and specify a different screen for different item in the list...

Comment: categories is a List<Categories> so one can get .length @Agkab, It would be better to create just one screen for all categories and simply pass the category data needed to render on this screen in the constructor of the class.

Comment: @lordvidex Thank you, he has just modified it. It wasn't the same code. The code was edited .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp()); // main function 

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {  // MyApp class
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      initialRoute: '/home',
      routes: {
        '/home': (context) => Home(),
        categories[0].route: (context) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text(categories[0].categoryName)),
            body: Text(categories[0].categorySubTitle)),  //first route
        categories[1].route: (context) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text(categories[1].categoryName)),
            body: Text(categories[1].categorySubTitle)),  // second route
      },
    //Here to simplify things, you can create a variable of type Map<String,
    // Widget Function(BuildContext)> and then assign it to route
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Material App Bar'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: categories.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(categories[index].categoryName),
            subtitle: Text(categories[index].categoryName),
            onTap: () =>
                Navigator.pushNamed(context , categories[index].route),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Categories {  //Categories class
  final String route;
  final String categoryName;
  final String categorySubTitle;
  Categories({this.route, this.categoryName, this.categorySubTitle});
}

final Categories tarocchi = Categories(
  route: '/tarocchi',
  categoryName: 'Tarocchi e Divinazione',
  categorySubTitle: 'L’antica arte dei Tarocchi e della Divinazione',
);
final Categories sogni = Categories(
  route: '/sogni',
  categoryName: 'Interpretazione dei Sogni',
  categorySubTitle: 'Significato e interpretazione dei Sogni',
);

List<Categories> categories = [tarocchi, sogni]; //List of categories
```

> I think this is what you're looking for. You can use that as a basis
> for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You Should use `Named Route`.You should create name routes for all your screens
Example:
In MaterialApp

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'My App',
  initialRoute: '/home',
  routes: {'home': (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen(),
            'settings': (BuildContext context) => SettingsScreen(),
    },
 ),
```

In Your `ListViewBuilder` change your `onTap` like this

```
() => Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'home'); // 'home' should be same as key that you give in `routes` in `MaterialApp`
```

This will fix the issue.

create `category` array like this,

```
final Categories tarocchi = Categories(
    id: 1,
    categoryName: 'Tarocchi e Divinazione',
    categoryImage: 'assets/images/tarot.jpg',
    categorySubTitle: 'L’antica arte dei Tarocchi e della Divinazione',
    categoryDescription: 'L’antica arte dei Tarocchi e della Divinazione',
    categoryRoute: 'home'

);
final Categories sogni = Categories(
    id: 2,
    categoryName: 'Interpretazione dei Sogni',
    categoryImage: 'assets/images/dreams.jpg',
    categorySubTitle: 'Significato e interpretazione dei Sogni',
    categoryDescription: 'Significato e interpretazione dei Sogni'
    categoryRoute: 'settings'

);

List<Categories> categories = [tarocchi, sogni,aromaterapia,cristalloterapia,naturopatia,ascolto,sciamanesimo,regressioni];
```

Comment: I think here miss a piece, and the Categories Class?
each element into a categories class has a different screen as you can see above...
what to use into each element of Categories List to move to the right screen?

Comment: Hai Agos Dev, Please refer the edited answer,i have added categories array

Comment: with: Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'home'); 
all the element of the list push to the same Screen I there there need a INDEX of the list.